# Partially initializing domain entities

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

In the following, author advises to not partially initialize domain entities.

> As we stated earlier, each customer must have no more than 5 contacts. By not returning the contacts along with the customers themselves, we leave a hole in our domain model which allows us to add a 6th contact and thus break this invariant.
>
> Because of that, the practice of partial initialization should be avoided. If your repository returns a list of domain entities (or just a single domain entity), make sure the entities are fully initialized meaning that all their properties are filled out.
> https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/partially-initialized-entities-anti-pattern/

So, should we have to load the whole object graph? A customer with all contacts and all related things or entity framework lazy loading would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has less to do with the object graph and more to do with the invariants involved.

As someone posted in the comments of that post, a performance issue may very well arise when there are 1000's of permitted contacts.  An example of something to this effect may be that a `Customer` may only have, say, 5 active `Order` instances.  Should *all* order instances linked to the customer be loaded?  Most certainly not.  In fact, an `Order` is another aggregate and an *instance* of one aggregate should not be contained in another aggregate.  You *could* use a ***value object*** containing the id of the other aggregate but for a great many of these the same performance issue may manifest itself.

An alternative may be to simply keep a `ContactCount` or, in my example, an `ActiveOrderCount` which is kept consistent.  If the actual relationships are to be stored/removed then these may be attached to the relevant aggregate when adding/removing in order to persist the change but that is a transient representation.

> So, should we have to load the whole object graph? A customer with all contacts and all related things or entity framework lazy loading would help?

The answer is, actually, a resounding **"yes"**.  However, your object model should not be deep.  You should make every attempt to create small aggregates.  I try to model my aggregates with a single root entity and then containing value objects.  The entire aggregate is loaded.  Lazy-loading is probably an indication that you are querying your domain which is something that I suggest one *not* do.  Rather create a simple *query* mechanism that uses some *read model* to return return the relevant data for your front-end.

Answer (score 1):

The anti-pattern of partially loaded entities has to do with both graphs (children and relatives) as well as data within an entity. The reason it is an anti-pattern is because any code that is written to accept, and expect an entity should be given a complete and valid entity.

This is not to say that you *always* must load a complete entity, it is that if you ever return an entity, it should be a complete, or complete-able entity. (proxies associated to a live DbContext)

An example of a partially loaded example and why it goes bad:

Someone goes to write the following method that an MVC controller will call to get a customer and return it to a view...

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(string criteria)
{
   using (var context = new MyDbContext())
   {
       return context.Customers.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.CustomerName.StartsWith(criteria)).ToList();
   }
}
```

Code like this may have worked earlier with simpler entities, but Customer had related data like Orders and when MVC went to serialize it, they got an error because the Orders proxies could not lazy load due to the DbContext being disposed. The options were to somehow eager-load all related details with this call to return the complete customer, completely disable lazy loading proxies, or return an incomplete customer.  Since this method would be used to display a summary list of just customer details, the author could choose to do something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(string criteria)
{
   using (var context = new MyDbContext())
   {
       return context.Customers.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.CustomerName.StartsWith(criteria))
           .Select(x => new Customer
           {
               CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
               CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
               // ... Any other fields that we want to display...
           }).ToList();
   }
}
```

The problem seems solved.  The trouble with this approach, or turning off lazy load proxies, is that you are returning a class that implies "I am a Customer Entity". That object may be serialized to a view, and de-serialized back from a view and passed to another method that is expecting a Customer Entity. Modifications to your code down the road will need to somehow determine which "Customer" objects are actually associated with a DbContext (or a complete, disconnected entity) vs. one of these partial, and incomplete Customer objects.

Eager-loading all of the related data would avoid the issue of the partial entity, however it is both wasteful in terms of performance and memory usage, and prone to bugs as entities evolve as when relatives are added they need to be eager-fetched in the repository or could result in lazy load hits, errors, or incomplete entity views getting introduced down the road.

Now in the early days of EF & NHibernate you would be advised to always return complete entities, or write your repositories to never return entities, instead, return DTOs. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerDTO> GetCustomers(string criteria)
{
   using (var context = new MyDbContext())
   {
       return context.Customers.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.CustomerName.StartsWith(criteria))
           .Select(x => new CustomerDTO
           {
               CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
               CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
               // ... Any other fields that we want to display...
           }).ToList();
   }
}
```

This is a better approach than the above one because by returning and using the CustomerDTO, there is absolutely no confusion between this partial object and a Customer entity. However, this solution has its drawbacks. One is that you may have several similar, but different views that need customer data, and some may need a bit extra or some of the related data. Other methods will have different search requirements. Some will want pagination or sorting. Using this approach will be similar to the article's example where you end up with a repository returning several similar, but different DTOs with a large number of variant methods for different criteria, inclusions, etc. (CustomerDTO, CustomerWithAddressDTO, etc. etc.)

With modern EF there is a better solution available for repositories, and that is to return `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than `IEnumerable<TEntity>` or even `TEntity`. For example, to search for customers leveraging `IQueryable`:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    return Context.Customers.Where(x => x.IsActive)
}
```

Then, when your MVC Controller goes to get a list of customers with it's criteria:

```
using (var contextScope = ContextScopeFactory.Create())
{
    return CustomerRepository.GetCustomers()
         .Where(x => x.CustomerName.Contains(criteria)
         .Select(x => new CustomerViewModel
         {
             CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
             CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
             // ... Details from customer and related entities as needed.
         }).ToList();
}
```

By returning `IQueryable` the repository does not need to worry about complete vs. incomplete representations of entities. It can enforce core rules such as active state checking, but leave it up to the consumers to filter, sort, paginate, or otherwise consume the data as they see fit. This keeps the repositories very lightweight and simple to work with while allowing controllers and services that consume them to be unit tested with mocks in place of the repositories. The controllers should consume the entities returned by the repository, but take care not to return these entities themselves. Instead they can populate view models (or DTOs) to hand over to the web client or API consumer to avoid partial entities being passed around and confused for real entities.

This applies to cases even when a repository is expected to return just 1 entity, returning `IQueryable` has it's advantages.

for instance, comparing:

```
public Customer GetCustomerById(int customerId)
{
     return Context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
}
```

vs.

```
public IQueryable<Customer> QGetCustomerById(int customerId)
{
     return Context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
}
```

These look very similar, but to the consumer (controller/service) it would be a bit different.

```
var customer = CustomerRepository.GetCustomerById(customerId);
```

vs.

```
var customer = CustomerRepository.QGetCustomerById(customerId).Single();
```

Slightly different, but the 2nd is far more flexible. If we just wanted to check if a customer existed?

```
var customerExists = CustomerRepository.GetCustomerById(customerId) != null;
```

vs.

```
var customerExists = CustomerRepository.QGetCustomerById(customerId).Any();
```

The first would execute a query that loads the entire customer entity. The second merely executes an Exists check query.  When it comes to loading related data? The first method would need to rely on lazy loading or simply not have related details available, where as the `IQueryable`  method could:

```
var customer = CustomerRepository.QGetCustomerById(customerId).Include(x => x.Related).Single();
```

or better, if loading a view model with or without related data:

```
var customerViewModel = CustomerRepository.QGetCustomerById(customerId)
    .Select(x => new CustomerViewModel
    {
        CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
        RelatedName = x.Related.Name,
        // ... etc.
    }).Single();
```

Disclaimer: Actual mileage may vary depending on your EF version. EF Core has had a number of changes compared to EF6 around lazy loading and query building.

A requirement for this pattern is that the DbContext either has to be injected (DI) or provided via a unit of work pattern as the consumer of the repository will need to interact with the entities and their DbContext when materializing the query created by the repository.

A case where using a partially initialized entity is perfectly valid would be when performing a Delete without pre-fetching the entity. For instance in cases where you're certain a particular ID or range of IDs needs to be deleted, rather than loading those entities to delete you can instantiate a new class with just that entity's PK populated and tell the DbContext to delete it.  The key point when considering the use of incomplete entities would be that it is only cases where the entity only lives within the scope of the operation and is not returned to callers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Please check this article about returning IQueryable; https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/  Don’t return IQueryable<T> from repositories, it brings up issues with DRY and LSP violation and leaking database concerns to the application logic.

Comment: I cover off the apparent "leaking" of data concerns in my response (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807269/returning-domain-objects-from-repositories-on-joining-tables/59815964#59815964) Regarding DRY - DRY applies to *identical* logic, not merely similar logic. When multiple controllers want to access data, they more typically than not have unique requirements of that data. Trying to abstract and standardize those requirements in the repository leads to very large repository classes and/or very complex ones, or inefficient calling code. EF + IQueryable keeps it simple and flexible.

Comment: The IQueryable repository still enforces identical requirements such as multi-tenancy, soft delete, etc. DRY is concern for re-factoring once business logic is proven. I view trying to constrain business logic with standardized repository calls is premature optimization, and leads to sub-obptimal performing code. KISS > DRY.  For the LSP concern, using a Unit of Work pattern manages the lifetime scope of the DbContext. All repositories operate within a lifetime scope and entities never leave that scope. (Controllers compose ViewModels to return or consume entities on the spot.)